# Passing Property Values from Parent UserControl to Child's DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, binding, dependency-properties

How to pass **property** (**SomeProperty**) from **ParentUserControl** context to **DependencyProperty** (**MyDProperty**) of the **ChildUserControl**?

In XAML, it should be: **<uc:ChildUserControl MyDProperty="{Binding SomeProperty}">**
but, for some reason, MyDProperty **never gets set** with Parent.DataContext.SomeProperty.

In my case, I'm passing an Action, but that's not important. I think the issue lies in the binding.

---

ParentUserControl:

```
    public Action RemoveEsl1 => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

---

```
    <uc:ChildUserControl Title="ESL 1" RemoveEslAction="{Binding RemoveEsl1}" DataContext="{Binding Esl1}"/>
```

---

ChildUserControl:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemoveEslActionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(RemoveEslAction), typeof(Action), typeof(ChildUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(delegate { }));


    public Action RemoveEslAction
    {
        get => (Action)GetValue(RemoveEslActionProperty);
        set => SetValue(RemoveEslActionProperty, value);
    }
```

I found various tips here, but none of them either suited me or worked.

Comment: How do you verify that the property "*never gets set*"? There is no PropertyChangedCallback where you could set a breakpoint. The property setter will not be called when the property is set by a Binding.

Comment: It is also unclear whether `Esl1` is actually a property of the current DataContext, and what `DataContext="{Binding Esl1}"` is supposed to do when `RemoveEsl1` is a property of the parent element. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Clemens I call RemoveEslAction in ChildUserControl when needed, but RemoveEslAction is always null. Also, the RemoveEsl1 property is never read by anyone.

Comment: Instead of binding the ChildUserControl's DataContext, you would use a RelativeSource Binding like `RemoveEslAction="{Binding RemoveEsl1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ParentUserControl}}"`.

Comment: As a general hint, always take a look at the Output Window in Visual Studio for possible data binding error messages when you debug your application.

Comment: @Clemens 
In my case, Esl1 is a class whose instance is located in ParentUserControl and is passed as DataContext to ChildUserControl.

Comment: @Clemens I tried using RemoveEslAction="{Binding RemoveEsl1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ParentUserControl}}" in ParentUserControl, but it triggers a XamlParseException: Type reference cannot find type named '{http://schemas.... ParentUserControl}'. If I use AncestorType=UserControl, nothing changes. Only when I remove DataContext="{Binding Esl1}", RemoveEslAction is set correctly, but then I lose the necessary DataContext in ChildUserControl. Is there a simple way to just pass some value from the parent DataContext to the ChildUserControl without changing its DataContext?

Comment: The RelativeSource Binding should work independently of the DataContext. No idea whether ParentUserControl is actually a parent element of ChildUserControl. You haven't shown that. As said, provide a reproducible example. Don't let us guess what you're doing.

Comment: @Clemens in the response, I mentioned one of the solutions to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question (check ParentUserControl):

**Models**:

```
public class RootModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ParentModel parentModel = new();
    public ParentModel ParentModel { get => parentModel; set => RisePropertyChanged(ref parentModel, value); }
}

public class ParentModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ChildModel childModel = new();
    public ChildModel ChildModel { get => childModel; set => RisePropertyChanged(ref childModel, value); }

    public string ParentModelProperty => "Correct value from ParentModel";
}

public class ChildModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string childModelProperty = "Wrong default value from ChildModel";
    public string ChildModelProperty { get => childModelProperty; set => RisePropertyChanged(ref childModelProperty, value); }
}
```

**MainWindow**:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <model:RootModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<uc:ParentUserControl DataContext="{Binding ParentModel}"/>
```

**ParentUserControl**:

```
<uc:ChildUserControl ChildDependency="{Binding DataContext.ParentModelProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" DataContext="{Binding ChildModel}"/>
```

**ChildUserControl**:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="Dependency property:"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding ChildDependency, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    <Separator/>
    <Label Content="Property:"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding ChildModelProperty}"/>
</StackPanel>


public partial class ChildUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildDependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ChildDependency), typeof(string), typeof(ChildUserControl), new ("Wrong default DP value from ChildUserControl"));

    public string ChildDependency
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ChildDependencyProperty);
        set => SetValue(ChildDependencyProperty, value);
    }

    public ChildUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

So this is how to pass a property (ParentModelProperty) from ParentUserControl context to DependencyProperty (ChildDependency) of the ChildUserControl.

Comment: I still don't know how to pass some value in a similar way to some property in ChildUserControl